# Using a callback interface to handle asynchronous volley request, response isn't handled properly

Tags: java, android, callback, android-volley

I'm using a Navigation Drawer activity into which I'm loading a listview fragment, where some text retrieved from the server is supposed to be loaded. I'm using volley to send a JSON Object request to retrieve the data. I'm using a callback interface implementation to ensure that the activity will wait for the reponse. In all the other instances that I have used it, it has worked perfectly well. But in this instance it is not, as the control is transferred back to the OnCreate method without waiting for the callback implementation method finishing. I'll illustrate in the code below.

```
//import statements
public class HomeTypeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Toolbar toolbar = null;
NavigationView navigationView = null;
MenuItem item;
final ArrayList<String> updates_list = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> time_list = new ArrayList<String>();
private RequestQueue queue;
private final String server_url = "http://10.0.2.2";
private StringBuilder get_updates_time_url = new StringBuilder(server_url).append("get_updates.php");
final String TAG = "Loggin";
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Fragment Updates_Fragment = null;
Fragment Clients_Fragment = null;
Fragment Reminders_Fragment = null;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_type);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    fabAction();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    try {
        Updates_Fragment = (Fragment) Updates.class.newInstance();
        Reminders_Fragment = (Fragment) Upcoming_Reminders.class.newInstance();
        Clients_Fragment = (Fragment) ClientList.class.newInstance();
        //Updates_Fragment

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
    }     
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    Class FragmentClass = Updates.class;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) FragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    setTitle(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getTitle());
    Bundle confirm = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (confirm == null)
        return;
    else {
        String message = confirm.getString("user_full_name");
        String client_toast = confirm.getString("client_message");
        if (message == null)
            return;
        if (toast_flag) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + message + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            toast_flag = false;
        }
        if (client_toast != null)
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Populator();

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, bundle.getStringArrayList("updates_array").toString());
    } //Catching a null pointer exception here as Populator method returns without having waited for the response
catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, exception.toString() + " null bundle why?");
    } 

    Updates_Fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}

 public interface UpdatesVolleyCallback{

    public void onResponse(JSONObject response);
}


public void Populator() {


    Log.i(TAG, "callback interface implementer");
    timeVolleyRequest(Request.Method.POST, get_updates_time_url.toString(), new UpdatesVolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("updates");
                        //Log.i(TAG, array.toString());
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            String update = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("update_string");
                            //Log.i(TAG, update);
                            String time = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("update_time");
                            //Log.i(TAG, time);
                            updates_list.add(update);
                            time_list.add(time);
                            Log.i(TAG, updates_list.toString());                              
                    bundle.putStringArrayList("updates_array",updates_list);                          
} 
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
            });

}


public void timeVolleyRequest(int method, String url, final UpdatesVolleyCallback callback) {
    Log.i(TAG, "I'm at volley!");
    queue = MySingleton.getInstance(HomeTypeActivity.this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    final ArrayList<String> updates_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> time_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Inside response!");
            callback.onResponse(response);


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeTypeActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Could not connect to the network. Try again later!")
                    .setTitle("Error!");
            builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

}
```

And here is the contents of the Log based on my tags

```
09-28 16:11:21.026 4013-4013/com.onerooftechnologiesamc I/Loggin: callback interface implementer yo
09-28 16:11:21.027 4013-4013/com.onerooftechnologiesamc I/Loggin: I'm at volley!
09-28 16:11:21.042 4013-4013/com.onerooftechnologiesamc I/Loggin: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.ArrayList.toString()' on a null object reference null bundle why?
09-28 16:11:21.793 4013-4013/com.onerooftechnologiesamc I/Loggin: Inside Response!
//And then here the response log tags are printed.
```

I've been debugging it for 2 days now. I tried replacing code, I even copy pasted the exact structure of the code I used for the other modules. What am I missing here? I even tried using wait() and notifyAll() but that just sent my whole app into a permanent blocking state. Even putting the OnCreate to sleep for 5 seconds sends the whole app into blocking before the null pointer exception is generated and everything is the same. Help is appreciated!

PS: I haven't copy pasted all the methods of the activity here!

Comment: have you tried printing your response??
if you can show the response by calling response.toString() that will helps to figure out the issue.

Comment: Yes I'm printing the response in the Log. It shows perfectly, but only after the OnCreate has thrown a Null Pointer Exception